# run two list same time on django template

Tags: django, django-templates

how to run two list same time on Django-templates without using zip function.

views.py

```
l1=[1,2,3]
l2=[4,5,6]
return render(request,'home.html',{'l1':l1,'l2':l2})
```

I am passing list this type on my template page now need to run both list same time on template. how can I do this.

Note---only I want do this on my template page

Answer (score 0):

In this case, try crate a template filter:

```
@register.filter(name='zip')
def zip_lists(a, b):
  return zip(a, b)
```

And in your template:

```
{%for a, b in l1|zip:l2 %}
  {{a}}
  {{b}}
{%endfor%}
```

By this way you don't need modify your views
More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: But it is not iterate. If we want iterate then need for loop. Just like zip method work as like i want same work do in template.